# How to send gmail from windows forms

Tags: c#, gmail

What I want is to create a software using C# winforms that can automate sending emails to various list of people.

What I'd tried was this implementation:

```
try
{
    SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");
    client.Port = 587;
    client.EnableSsl = true;
    client.Timeout = 100000;
    client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
    client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
    client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(
        "yourid@gmail.com", "yourgmailpassword");
    MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
    msg.To.Add(textBox_To.Text);
    msg.From = new MailAddress("yourid@gmail.com");
    msg.Subject = textBox_Subject.Text;
    msg.Body = textBox_Message.Text;
    Attachment data = new Attachment(textBox_Attachment.Text);
    msg.Attachments.Add(data);
    client.Send(msg);
    MessageBox.Show("Successfully Sent Message.");
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

But the problem is that, Google is not allowing this approach.
When I'm opening my gmail account, I get a ‘**Suspicious sign in prevented**’ email.

Any other approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's google's security feature. To workaround it, google gives you two options

> #### Change account access for less secure apps
>
> To help keep Google Apps
>   users' accounts secure, we may block less secure apps from accessing
>   Google Apps accounts. As a Google Apps user, you will see a "Password
>   incorrect" error when trying to sign in. If this is the case, you have
>   two options:
>
> - **Option 1**: Upgrade to a more secure app that uses the most up to date
>     security measures. All Google products, like Gmail, use the latest
>     security measures.
> - **Option 2**: Change your settings to allow less secure
>     apps to access your account. We don't recommend this option because it
>     might make it easier for someone to break into your account. If you
>     want to allow access anyway, follow these steps:
>
>   1. Go to the ["Less secure apps" section](https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps) in My Account.
>   2. Next to "Access for less secureapps," select **Turn on**. (**Note to Google Apps users**: This setting is
>        hidden if your administrator has locked less secure app account
>        access.)

Link: https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en